# Jhipster behind proxy nginx store local server ip instead of request IP in audit table

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, spring-security, jhipster

I'm setting up a tomcat with a JHipster 4.10.2 behind an NGINX proxy, and everything works well, but when I go to Audit view to show logged user... the stored IP is always the server IP. 
Sometimes the stored IP address is a localhost IP address 127.0.0.1 and other times is the server's public IP, not the client/user IP who logged in to the application.

I tested on java code to get the IP address from the request:

```
request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")
```

And this way I get the correct IP address (real IP address from the user who makes the call)
But I don't witch Java class I can modify or extend to get the IP address using this way.

I'm using use-forward-headers flag to true on application.yml and application-prod.yml

```
server.use-forward-headers = true
```

nginx config:

```
location /myapp {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/myapp;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try $http_x_real_ip, I got the answer from https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/forwarding-visitors-real-ip

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_real_ip;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but apparently isn't working for me...maybe it's something related to which flag is using my JHipster app to get the IP address.
I will check JHipster config and Java code.